# How do I connect two blocks using no more than 3 lines in JavaScript? Something like the onet connect game

Tags: javascript

Working on a **JavaScript** prototype  for a onet like game. I need to connect two blocks using no more than 3 lines.

Here is what I am trying to do

[image]

The lines can connect two blocks together or separated when it takes 3 lines to connect them. It can't connect blocks where there is another block "blocking" it or diagonally.

I have tried to use the pathfinding method but it doesn't work as expected because it looks for the shortest path but in this case it has to take into consideration that it should only takes 3 turns to get to the destination when possible)

I thought about using the floodfill method but I can't make it work in this example. I even found an interesting explanation online https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zwh-QNlsurI

Can anyone help me find a starting point algorithm for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the grid is 4x4, with each square being numbered top to bottom, left to right like this:

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

You want to match any two squares `x` and `y` where `y` is greater than `x` and:

```
y - x == 1 3 && (x+1) % 4 > 0 //for horizontally adjacent squares 
y - x == 4 //for vertically adjacent squares
y - x == 3 && (y+1) % 4 == 0 //for squares at opposite ends of a row
```

## Update: test case

```js
let grid = document.querySelector(".grid")

for(i=0;i<16;i++){
   let sq = document.createElement("div")
   sq.classList.add("sq")
   sq.dataset.id = i
   grid.appendChild(sq)
}

let squares = document.querySelectorAll(".sq")
let x = null,y = null
squares.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let dId = e.target.dataset.id
        if(!x){
            x = dId
            e.target.classList.add("x")
        }else if(!y){
            y = dId
            e.target.classList.add("y")
            checkIfWinner(x,y)
        }
    })
})

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = () => {
    console.clear()
    x=null
    y=null
    squares.forEach(el => {el.classList.remove("x"); el.classList.remove("y")})
}

function checkIfWinner(x,y){
    let high = x > y ? x : y
    let low = x > y ? y : x
    if( (high - low == 1 && (parseInt(low)+1) % 4 > 0) || high - low == 4 || (high - low == 3 && (parseInt(high)+1) % 4 == 0)){
        console.log("Winner")
    }else{
        console.log("Try Again")
    }
}
```

```css
.grid{
   display:inline-grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
   grid-gap: 4px;
}

.grid > div{
   border: solid 2px gray;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
}

h3{margin:0 0 5px}
.x{background-color: dodgerblue}
.y{background-color: orangered}
```

```html
<h3>Click any two squares<h3> 
<div class="grid"></div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I like your solution but there are two issues.
One, it connect horizontal or vertical. Two, the lines should be drawn if possible.
It should work like this » https://www.marketjs.com/item/onet-connect

Comment: This one works horizontally and vertically. The line drawing can be worked out pretty easily, I would look into the `::before` and `::after` pseudos for that.

Comment: Another issue is that it can't connect two blocks where there is a obstacle. For example, if you click on block 4 and then on block 7, it should validate it because the blocks 5 and 6 are obstacles for the line to get there.